# Why is it that the append method duplicates my on-click event results event though i set the div to empty before it is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

A loop runs through the array if usernames to get a request from the api for each of them. Then the div with the id of streamerOffline is set to empty.Now I click the button offline and get a list of all users who are offline.However when I click the button again the data gets just appends to the previous on click event and doesn't empty.Could someone help me out.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
// solution with call back function
var streamers = ["streamerhouse","ESL_SC2", "freecodecamp", "Test_channel"];
var offlineChannels = "";
$('#streamerOffline').empty();
//Getting the twtich requests
for (i=0; i < streamers.length; i++){
$.getJSON('https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/streams/'+streamers[i]+'', callData);

} //end for loop
$('#streamerOffline').empty();
function callData(data)
{
   $('#streamerOffline').empty();
    $(document).on('click', '#offlineNow', function(){ 

       if(data["stream"] === null){ 

             offlineChannels = "<p>"+data["_links"]["channel"]+"</p>";
             $('#streamerOffline').append(offlineChannels);     
       }


    });  

      $(document).on('click', '#onlineNow', function(){


       if (data["stream"] !== null ){

         if ( $('#streamerOnline').text() === null){
           alert("empty");
         }
         $('#streamerOnline').append("<p>"+data["stream"]["channel"]["status"]+"</p>");      

      }          
     });                 
}                
});
```

**Update:**
I tried setting the id to empty inside the if statement itself but because each time the for loop runs it is emptied. leaving me with only one of the two results expected.

```
 $(document).on('click', '#offlineNow', function(){ 

       if(data["stream"] === null){ 
               $('#streamerOffline').empty();
             offlineChannels = "<p>"+data["_links"]["channel"]+"</p>";
              $('#streamerOffline').append(offlineChannels);        
       }


    });
```

Comment: Side note: you could save yourself some unnecessary typing by using dot notation: e.g. `data._links.channel`, `data.stream.channel.status`, bracket notation should be reserved for dynamic property names.

Comment: ok thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

Always append after clearing previous data.

```
$(document).on('click', '#offlineNow', function(){ 
       if(data["stream"] === null){ 
             offlineChannels = "<p>"+data["_links"]["channel"]+"</p>";
             $('#streamerOffline').empty().append(offlineChannels);     
       }
});
```

Comment: I tried this suggestion before however if i have two results only one of the results will be displayed because after looping once it empties the div and places whatever is in the other iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that adding a new event listener on every iteration makes a lot of sense, especially since it is doing the same thing. I suggest that you instead create an array of all your users/streamers and filter the array based on which "button" (or whatever `#streamerOffline` is) is clicked:

```
var users = [];

// add each user to "users" array
for (i=0; i < streamers.length; i++){
    $.getJSON('https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/streams/'+streamers[i], function(user) {
        users.push(user);
    });
}

$(document).on('click', '#offlineNow', function() {
    var offlineUsers = users.filter(function(user) {
        return user.stream === null;
    });
    $('#streamerOffline').append(
        offlineUsers.map(function(user) {
            return '<p>' + user._links.channel + '</p>';
        })
    );
});

$(document).on('click', '#onlineNow', function() {
    // get users who are offline (stream !== null)
    var onlineUsers = users.filter(function(user) {
        return user.stream !== null;
    });
    $('#streamerOnline').empty().append(
        onlineUsers.map(function(user) {
            return '<p>' + user.stream.channel.status + '</p>';
        })
    );
});
```